# SQLite / .NET: Get table names for attached database

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I can easily get the table names from a System.Data.SQLiteConnection like this:

```
 Public Function GetTableNames(ByVal uCn As SQLite.SQLiteConnection, ByVal uDBName As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim nTables As New List(Of String)
    Dim dt As DataTable = uCn.GetSchema("tables")
    For Each nRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim sTableName As String = nRow(2)
        nTables.Add(sTableName)
    Next

    Return nTables

End Function
```

However, I don't see how I can determine which database exactely I want to use.
With the current approach, the table names are taken from the main database.

Does anybody know how I can say that want to get the table names from a specific database attached to the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetSchema` does not support attached databases.
You have read the table names directly from the [system table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master):

```
SELECT name FROM MyOtherDB.sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'
```